# Change of basis matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $E=(e_1, e_2,e_3,e_4)$ be the standard basis in $\mathbb R^4$ and let another basis be given by
$$
B = (\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
,\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
0\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
,\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
3\\
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
,\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
4\\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
).$$

What are the change of basis matrices from E to B and from B to E? Also why? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you wrote is no basis of $\,\Bbb R^4\,$ but simply a matrix, so: what did you exactly mean? To take the matrix's columns as vectors...?

Comment: yes, the columns are the basis vectors, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Given an arbitrary vector ($\alpha_1, \ldots)$ in basis $E$, you want to find the representation of that same vector in basis $B$:
$$\sum_i \alpha_i e_i = \sum_i \beta_i b_i.$$
What does this equation look like in matrix notation? How would you solve for the unknown $\beta_i$ if I give you $\alpha_i$?

Comment: This was on a test, and I said that the change of basis matrix of the change from E to B is given by $B^{-1}$ and the change of basis matrix from B to E is given by B. I got zero points.

Comment: You should go talk to the professor/TA; unless you are leaving out some parts of the problem (ie, maybe you were suppose to explicitly work out $B^{-1}$), that should be correct.